# Best method to calculate quality of string paragraph?

Tags: php

I have a cron job that searches through WordPress posts once a day and finds all posts with `>5000` post characters and assigns it a "high quality" category.

However I want to improve this system and actually judge the post content itself. Someone could for example post nothing but youtube links or garbage to hit the limit which would then get assigned the category.

Is there a good method in PHP to determine the quality of string contents in a variable?

I could be basic about it and hard count youtube links to determine it but I want to try be as thorough as possible.

EDIT: In terms of what "high quality" means in this scenario, it's a yugioh deck building site and users can post decks along with a deck description/guide.
Here is an example: https://ygoprodeck.com/shiranui-demon-slayers-of-zombie-world/

Currently testing for >5000 characters has worked (in this scenario it means they wrote a guide/good description) but this would not prevent a post with nothing but YouTube links or someone holding down the "A" key until they hit 5000.

Comment: what constitutes a "high quality" post though? perfect grammar? verified post author? is it factual (veracity) or just a made up content? what kind of content is it anyway

Comment: I've updated the post with an explanation Kevin, thanks

Comment: in this website, articles are divided by categories, the article above is in high quality. do you have some other reason why not use this? there's thumbs up too as well if you want to use that as measurement

Comment: The example given was something I DO want in high quality. I'm thinking forward where the system could be exploited (it currently isn't being exploited) by posting garbage text. I thought about using the meta values for thumbs up but that could potentially be exploited too

Comment: im not sure if PHP will be enough to do a true high quality evaluation of your content based on the topic / subject at hand (yugioh). you'd probably need some peer-review to do that. you could probably use keywords that are related to that subject, and add a scoring system. or you could venture into AI, but I have no knowledge in that subject matter. but good luck. and yes it's true you need more than the current mechanism that you have to gauge something as "high quality"